# How to find the highest field value in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

For example, say I have these documents in a collection named "items":

```
{
  rank: 1
}
{
  rank: 2
}
{
  rank: 3
}
```

How would I find the highest rank value (3) in the items collection to be assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the documents by rank and limit to one item.

```
MyCollection.findOne({}, {sort:{rank:-1}, limit: 1}); // Document with max rank
MyCollection.findOne({}, {sort:{rank:+1}, limit: 1}); // Document with min rank
```

So you get your max rank value like that:

```
var maxRank = MyCollection.findOne({}, {sort:{rank:-1}, limit: 1}).rank;
```

Comment: Will that give me the only value of rank?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
var arr = [{
  rank: 1
},
{
  rank: 2
},
{
  rank: 3
}];

var max;
for (var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
    if (!max || arr[i].rank > max){
       max = arr[i].rank;
    }
}
console.log(max);
```

Comment: I went that way at first, but I think he means a Mongo collection, not a javascript array. @garrett is that correct?

Comment: If it is so @garrett  should  use `sort({"rank":-1}) `and then limit to 1

Comment: Yes, using mongo. Sorry